# How can I get jQuery post to work with a salesforce WebToLead

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, salesforce

I have a page with a form that posts to salesforce.com's webto Lead service.
I am trying to make an ajax version of this using jQuery.

Though the form in the page posts fine and I receive the data in my salesforce, Once I make an identical post structure to this form and then post with jQuery I get a 405.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Is there a difference between a posted form and a jquery post as far as what the receiving website can see?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're running into here is referred to as the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which says that XmlHttpRequests must be to the same domain the script is running on.  If you need to do this via AJAX, it will need to post to a script running on your domain, which would then make the call out to SalesForce.

Comment: Ok so here's how I got it to work.
Firstly I ajax a post to a controller on my domain.
This then uses cURL to make a post from the domain to the external domain.
Viola!

Answer (score 4):

To avoid cross domain issues, use ajax to post to a script on your domain that then utilises cURL to make a post to the external domain.